# Php oop (__construct) file upload

Tags: php, mysql

I work on a oop class.php file. I want to implement function __contruct(). I don't know why it doesn't work.

I think there is error, but I don't know how to write it. `$args['file_upload'] = $_FILES['file_upload'][''] ?? NULL;`

Thanks.

**fileupload.class.php**

```
public function __construct($string){
    $this->filename      = $_FILES['$string']['name']['0']; 
    $this->temp_path     = $_FILES['$string']['tmp_name']['0'];
    $this->type      = $_FILES['$string']['type']['0'];
    $this->size      = $_FILES['$string']['size']['0'];

}   
public function create() {
       if(move_uploaded_file....
}
```

**fileupload.php**

```
if(is_post_request()) {

        //Create record using post parameters
        $args = [];
        $args['prod_name'] = $_POST['prod_name'] ?? NULL;
        $args['file_upload'] = $_FILES['file_upload'][''] ?? NULL;

        $image = new Imageupload($args);
        $result = $image->create();

          if($result === true) {
            $new_id = $image->id;
            $_SESSION['message'] = 'The image was uploaded.';
          } else {
            // show errors
          }
        } else {
          // display the form
          $image = [];
        }

<p><input name="file_upload[]" type="file" id="file_upload[]" value=""></p>

<p>Product name: <input type="text" name="prod_name" value="" /></p>
```

**UPDATE1** function works

```
public function add_files() {

    $this->filename     = $_FILES['file_upload']['name']['0'];  
    $this->temp_path    = $_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name']['0'];
    $this->type         = $_FILES['file_upload']['type']['0'];
    $this->size         = $_FILES['file_upload']['size']['0'];
}

$image = new Imageupload($args);
$image->add_files();
```

Comment: `__contruct` -> `__construct`

Comment: I made a mistake when rewriting

Comment: How did you determine that the constructor didn't work? Also, you should copy/paste your actual code instead of rewriting it. If you rewrite it, we won't be able to spot potential typos (and, as you've noticed, you might introduce new)

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare Imageupload::__construct()

Comment: Sounds like you've declared the constructor multiple times? Also, `$_FILES['$string']` will literally look for a key named `$string` (since it's inside single quotes). It should most likely be `$_FILES[$string]`. However, you're not passing in a string with the key name, you're passing in an array.

Comment: multiple times ['0'] ['1'] ['2'] ['3']...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're creating a wheel again? :)
Try one of the libraries has been created for this purpose.
https://github.com/brandonsavage/Upload

Install composer in you operating system and run the following command in your command line

```
composer require codeguy/upload
```

Html

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="foo" value=""/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File"/>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$storage = new \Upload\Storage\FileSystem('/path/to/directory');
$file = new \Upload\File('foo', $storage);

// Optionally you can rename the file on upload
$new_filename = uniqid();
$file->setName($new_filename);

// Validate file upload
// MimeType List => http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml
$file->addValidations(array(
    // Ensure file is of type "image/png"
    new \Upload\Validation\Mimetype('image/png'),

    //You can also add multi mimetype validation
    //new \Upload\Validation\Mimetype(array('image/png', 'image/gif'))

    // Ensure file is no larger than 5M (use "B", "K", M", or "G")
    new \Upload\Validation\Size('5M')
));

// Access data about the file that has been uploaded
$data = array(
    'name'       => $file->getNameWithExtension(),
    'extension'  => $file->getExtension(),
    'mime'       => $file->getMimetype(),
    'size'       => $file->getSize(),
    'md5'        => $file->getMd5(),
    'dimensions' => $file->getDimensions()
);

// Try to upload file
try {
    // Success!
    $file->upload();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // Fail!
    $errors = $file->getErrors();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Good suggestion "Looks like you're creating a wheel again" :)

Comment: But I like to do everything myself.

Comment: @Syriusz You're welcome :D,  but i thought you're stuck. anyways enjoy coding :)